# Boolean numpy arrays with Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython, memoryview, typed-memory-views

I have a numpy boolean array:

```
myarr = np.array([[False, True], [True, False]])
```

If I try to initialise a Cython MemoryView with it, like this:

```
cdef bint[:,:] mymem = myarr
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('?')
```

If I do this instead, it works fine:

```
cdef np.int_t[:,:] mymem = np.int_(myarr)
```

How can I store a boolean numpy array using Cython MemoryViews?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same problem some time ago. Unfortunately I did not find a direct solution to this. But there is another approach: Since an array of boolean vales has the same data type size as `uint8`, you could use a memory view with this type as well. Values in the `uint8` memory view can also be compared to boolean values, so the behavior is mostly equal to an actual `bint` memory view:

```
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
ctypedef np.uint8_t uint8

cdef int i
cdef np.ndarray array = np.array([True,False,True,True,False], dtype=bool)
cdef uint8[:] view = np.frombuffer(array, dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(view.shape[0]):
    if view[i] == True:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
2
3
```

Answer (score 9):

This information seems to be not easy to find, [my reference](http://cython-docs2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html) is pretty old (2011), but not much seems to have changed since then.

Numpy's bool-array uses a 8bit-value for False/True (this is not obvious per se - C++'s `std::vector<bool>` uses for example 1 bit per value) with `0`-meaning `False` and `1`-meaning `True`. You can use `cast=True` for an `unit8`-array in order to use it as a `bool`-array, for example:

```
 %%cython
 import numpy as np
 cimport numpy as np
 def to_bool_array(lst):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim = 1, cast=True] res
    res=np.array(lst, dtype=bool)
    return res
```

And now:

```
 >>> to_bool_array([True,False,True,False])
 array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Setting `cast=True` gives some slack to Cython's type-checking, so the numpy-arrays with the same element-size (for example `uint8`, `int8` and `bool`) can be reinterpreted. This however would not work if element-sizes were different: for example `np.int8`(1byte) and `np.int16` (2bytes).

Answer (score 0):

I found it simplest to do:

```
cdef uint8_t[:] arr_memview8 = data.astype(np.uint8)
bool* ptr = <bool*>&arr_memview8[0]
```